# Login for two type of Users through same login page

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two type of users: Passenger and Driver. How can i make one login page for both users in asp.net C#
login page for passenger:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();


        cmd.CommandText = "SP_SELECT_Login1";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
        ad.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["UserId"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Reg_id"].ToString();
            Session["Username"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fname"].ToString();



            Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Incorrect User and Password or Unverify user";
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you have a single login page which helps to login two types of user. So you can do one thing that, maintain the user type in User's table, for every time while sign in to the page from Your Stored Procedure get that userType and give condition like below

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Session["UserId"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Reg_id"].ToString();
        Session["Username"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fname"].ToString();

        int userType = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserType"]);
       if(userType ==1) // Assume "1" for Driver
       {
        Response.Redirect("DriverProfile.aspx");
       }
       else //other than "1"/ driver(As per your query you have only two types of users)
       {
           Response.Redirect("PassengerProfile.aspx");
       }
    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Incorrect User and Password or Unverify user";
    }
```

based on above condition, based on user type the it will redirect to the respected user profile.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not quite clear. Can you clarify because, if you have userA and userB  and you pass userA credentials then from the db you'll get the userA info and if you write credentials for userB then you'll get userB info.